# working with treeview list from ObjectListView control

Tags: c#, objectlistview

i have download objectlistview from this site **http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html**

i am working with treelistview control from objectlistview project. i am working with `treelistview DoubleClick event` and from there i am trying to capture selected item text and as well selected item immediate parent item text

i could successfully capture selected item text like this way from double click event

```
private void tvView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(tvView.FocusedItem.SubItems[1].Text);
}
```

now help me to capture the selected item immediate parent item text. here is the pic which help other to understand what i am trying to capture.
[image]

just see the image that i click on item or row `whose immediate parent data 2` which i want to capture immediately. please guide me if any body worked with treelistview control. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ObjectListView/TreeListView you should never use the underlying ListView itself or the ListViewItem objects. [Read this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html#mental-gear-shift)

Using the TreeListView in comparison to the ObjectListView is a bit cumbersome.

Example (ignoring the double-click requirement):

```
private void tvView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // cast your TreeView to ObjectListView to access the selected Object
    ObjectListView olv = sender as ObjectListView;

    // get the selected child (you may want to check the type and if it really was a child that was selected here)
    MyChildModelObject child = olv.SelectedObject as MyChildModelObject;
    MyParentModelObject parent = _tvView.GetParent(child);

    // ...
}
```

Since you did not mention the models, I assumed that you have two different model objects in your tree hierarchy (MyChildModelObject and MyParentModelObject).